# Take photo button of UIImagePickerController does not work

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I put this code into two projects. In one project, I just need to press take photo button and it takes a photo. In another project, I must long press the button to take a photo. Please help me.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: is there use of any TapGestures in your project?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in swift..

```
   var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBAction func takepic(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
    imagePicker.cameraDevice = .Front;


    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: thank you but there is nothing wrong with my code if I run it in other project, what I seek for help is why I must long press in my main project